# Removing all meshes from a collection with Python

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I have 2 collections in a scene (collection, items) both with objects (meshes, camera, lights). How can I select all objecst of type mesh from items and delete them?

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
```

With that I can delete all from the scene but I want to limit it to delete all meshes from items. Probably I can if the collection name and type mesh but maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, i'm actually  trying to convert your Slider Puzzle script from 2014 to blender 2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think there is a simpler way (as you mentioned in the question).

Globally:

- Get the collection
- Iterate over mesh objects in the collection
- Keep its inner mesh data
- Remove the object

Then (optional):

- Iterate over the collected meshes
- Look if it has became orphean (no user)
- If yes, delete it

Commented code:

```
import bpy

collection_name = "items"

# Get the collection from its name
collection = bpy.data.collections[collection_name]

# Will collect meshes from delete objects
meshes = set()

# Get objects in the collection if they are meshes
for obj in [o for o in collection.objects if o.type == 'MESH']:
    # Store the internal mesh
    meshes.add( obj.data )
    # Delete the object
    bpy.data.objects.remove( obj )

# Look at meshes that are orphean after objects removal
for mesh in [m for m in meshes if m.users == 0]:
    # Delete the meshes
    bpy.data.meshes.remove( mesh )
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that work great for me

Comment: Works great :) thank you